# How to add a plus Button in ListView Builder fetches the data from SQLite in Flutter

Tags: flutter, listview, sqflite

I have a `ListView Builder` where I have one `Stateful Widget`. I want to add a plus `Button` as `Widget` inside the `ListView Item`. What I am doing is that, I have added a number of records in SQLite when creating the database, and I have added a plus Icon and an empty as record/row to the database. So I am fetching the data from there. The Plus Button(Widget) is displaying as I expect but when update the data into the database the `Button` is not Showing at the Expected position, Because I want it to display at the end of all the items.

```
       class CategoriesScreen extends StatefulWidget {
       @override
       _CategoriesScreenState createState() => _CategoriesScreenState();
        }

       class _CategoriesScreenState extends State<CategoriesScreen> {
        List<Map<String,dynamic>> spendingCategoriesList=[] ;
         DatabaseHelper helper=DatabaseHelper();
         @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
          getData();

return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Color(0xFF343641),
  body: Container(

    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height-100,
    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 40.0),


    child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          width:MediaQuery.of(context).size.width ,
          height: 30.0,
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0),
          child: Row(

            children: [
              GestureDetector(
                onTap:(){Navigator.pop(context);},
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.close,
                  color: Color(0xFFE44663),
                  size: 24.0,
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left:MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.3),
                child: Text('Categories',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,fontSize: 15.0,),),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: GridView.builder(
              itemCount: spendingCategoriesList.length,
              gridDelegate: new SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 3), itemBuilder: (context,index){
            AddTransactionsModel transactionModel= new AddTransactionsModel(spendingCategoriesList[index]['CategoryImage'],spendingCategoriesList[index]['categoryName']);
            return AddTransactionItem(transactionModel);
          }),
        ),

      ],
    ),
  ),
);
     }

      void getData() async{
spendingCategoriesList=await helper.getNoteMapList();
setState(()  {
  spendingCategoriesList=spendingCategoriesList;

});

     
 }
```

Here is the AddTransactionGridItem;

```
class _AddTransactionItemState extends State<AddTransactionItem> {
var imageSelectIndex;
String categoryName;
 String categoryImage;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {


print(
    'Hello dear ! icon Number ${widget.transactionModel.iconNumber}  and here is Text ${widget.transactionModel.categoryNumber} ');

return Container(
  child: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      InkWell(
        onTap: widget.transactionModel.categoryNumber == ''
            ? () {
                showAddCategoryDialogue();
              }
            : () {
          setState(() {
            categoryName=widget.transactionModel.categoryNumber;
            categoryImage=widget.transactionModel.iconNumber;

            print('categoryName  $categoryName     And categoryImage   $categoryImage');
            String cate='$categoryName&$categoryImage';

            Navigator.pop(context,cate);
          });

        },
        child: Container(
          width: 72.0,
          height: 72.0,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Color(0xffC4C4C4).withOpacity(0.2),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12.0)),
            border: widget.transactionModel.categoryNumber == ''
                ? Border.all(width: 0.3, color: Colors.white)
                : Border.all(width: 0.0),
          ),
          child: Center(
              child: Image.asset('${widget.transactionModel.iconNumber}')),
        ),
      ),
      SizedBox(
        height: 10.0,
      ),
      Text(
        widget.transactionModel.categoryNumber,
        style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
            fontSize: 16.0,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
            fontFamily: 'Rajdhani',
            fontStyle: FontStyle.normal),
      )
    ],
  ),
);
```

}

Above`Container` is the `ListView.Builder() Item` .

Comment: I would appreciate if someone can help me ?

Comment: Could you share a snippet on how you're populating the ListView widget and adding the 'plus' button at the end of the List? The code snippet shared is only for the Container of the ListView items. I'm curious on how the ListView is populated.



Have you tried populating the ListView widget with static data and see if the 'plus' button is displayed? If it works, then populating the ListView widget with SQLite data shouldn't have issues, unless there's something else causing this behavior.

Comment: I have Edited my Question